# Debugging a program that is opened by pwntools

Tags: gdb, stack-overflow, pwntools

I am trying to do a stackoverflow for a course at university. The binary I am to exploit has a canary, however, there is a way to leak that canary to stdout. The canary of course consists of some random bytes so I can't just read them from the string that the program outputs to stdout.

For this reason I am using the python and pwntools like `p.recv(timeout = 0.01).encode("hex")`.
*(I'm using pwntools only because I don't know another way to read the output in hex format, if there is an easier way I can of course use something else)*

This works more or less works as expected, I manage to write the memory area that is past the canary. However, I get a segfault, so I obviously have some problem with the stackoverflow I am causing. I need a way of debugging this, like seeing the stack after I provide the input that causes the stackoverflow.

And now without any further ado the actual question: **Can I debug a process that I started with pwntools (like `process("./myprog")`) in GDB or some other program that can show me the content of the stack?**

I already tried getting the pid in python and using gdb attach to attach to that pid, but that didn't work.

*Note: The binary I am trying to exploit has the guid set. Don't know if that matters tho.*

Answer (score 14):

You can use the [pwnlib.gdb](https://docs.pwntools.com/en/stable/gdb.html) to interface with gdb.

You can use the gdb.attach() function:
From the docs:

```
bash = process('bash')

# Attach the debugger
gdb.attach(bash, '''
set follow-fork-mode child
break execve
continue
''')

# Interact with the process
bash.sendline('whoami')
```

or you can use gdb.debug():

```
# Create a new process, and stop it at 'main'
io = gdb.debug('bash', '''
# Wait until we hit the main executable's entry point
break _start
continue

# Now set breakpoint on shared library routines
break malloc
break free
continue
''')

# Send a command to Bash
io.sendline("echo hello")

# Interact with the process
io.interactive()
```

The pwntools template contains code to get you started with debugging with gdb. You can create the pwntools template by running `pwn template ./binary_name > template.py`. Then you have to add the GDB arg when you run template.py to debug: `./template.py GDB`.

If you get `[ERROR] Could not find a terminal binary to use.`, you might need to set `context.terminal` before you use gdb.

If you're using tmux, the following will automatically open up a gdb debugging session in a new horizontally split window:
    `context.terminal = ["tmux", "splitw", "-h"]`

And to split the screen with the new gdb session window vertically:
    `context.terminal = ["tmux", "splitw", "-v"]`

<strike>(Note: I never got this part working, so idk if it'll work. Tell me if you get the gdb thing working).</strike>
(To use tmux, install tmux on your machine, and then just type `tmux` to start it. Then type `python template.py GDB`.

If none of the above works, then you can always just start your script, use `ps aux`, find the PID, and then use `gdb -p PID` to attach to the running process.